# Css :hover although element not in front

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, drag

im writing a website on which pictures, ordered in a grid, are shown. I want to make it possible to drag them around with the mouse and zoom in and out with the mouse wheel. This already works so far. here is what my code looks like:

```
        var clicked = [0,0];
        var pos = [0,0]; // <-- This ist the position of the image(s)
        var dragging = false
        var zoom = 1;


        //this function is for zooming in and out
        window.onmousewheel = function(event)
        {
            if (event.deltaY > 0)
            {
                zoom *= 0.9;
            }
            else
            {
                 zoom *= 1.1;
            }
            update(0, 0);
        }
        window.onmousedown = function(event)
        {
            clicked = [event.clientX, event.clientY];
            dragging = true;  
        }
        window.onmousemove = function(event)
        {
            if (dragging == false){return;}
            update((event.clientX-clicked[0]),(event.clientY-clicked[1]))
        }
        window.onmouseup = function(event)
        {
            pos = [pos[0] + (event.clientX-clicked[0]), pos[1] + (event.clientY-clicked[1])]; 
            dragging = false;
        }

        function update(addX, addY) //<-- this function just updades the position of the images by using the zoom and pos variable and the addX and addY parameter
```

All of this works very fine. But it has one Bug: When i'm start draging while the mouse is directly over one of the images, then when i release the mouse the mouseup event is not triggered an so everything is still moving until you click again with your mouse. What i also do not like is that if you are dragging while the mouse is over one of the images, it shows this standard chrome browser image moving thing.
My Idea for solving this problems was, making a div with opacity: 0; in the front over everything, which fits the whole screen. looks like this:
(css)

```
            #controller
            {
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                bottom:0;
                right:0;
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                z-index: 999;
                opacity: 0; 
            }

(html)
            <div id="controller"></div>
```

And now it works fine. I also can drag when i start with the mouse direct over an image. But then i realized that now i can not make any click event or an simple css :hover over one of the images anymore, obviously because the invisible div is now in the front :(

Has anyone of you an idea how two solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Put the `onmouseup` inside `onmousedown`:

```
window.onmousedown = function(event)
    {
        clicked = [event.clientX, event.clientY];
        dragging = true;  
        window.onmouseup = function(event)
        {
            pos = [pos[0] + (event.clientX-clicked[0]), pos[1] + (event.clientY-clicked[1])]; 
            dragging = false;
        }
    }
```